# How can I take JSON that is PUT to an endpoint and then it POST to another API endpoint?

Tags: php, json, laravel, rest, web-services

Sorry, a very broad question I know. Basically, I'm trying to figure out the best way to take JSON that is PUT from Menulog's API (Just Eat API), do some work on it and then POST that on to Onfleet's API. Essentially I'm trying to take a restaurant order from Menulog's API and then use that data to create a delivery task within Onfleet's API.

I would just like to know generally how I would go about achieving this. I have some experience working with PHP and Laravel and deploying to a VM.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't know the two APIs, but what you can do is have the first system (MenuLog) send the PUT request to an endpoint/route of yours. Your controller can handle any modifications after decoding the JSON and then encode it before sending it to the second system (Onfleet).

Comment: Instead of conceptualizing a task as a single, complicated, contiguous task break down into it's component parts and solve them individually. 1. Accept data from source. 2. Adjust data format. 3. Issue request to destination. Now when you encounter a specific problem with an individual task, come on back with details and your question will be on-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, PUTed data may be accessed using `php://input` stream.

Below a sample code that returns input data (any POST/PUT/DELETE http method) as JSON:

```
function Input() {
    $Input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    return empty($Input) ? [] : json_decode($Input, true);
}
```

Later, you may use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library to post data to other web-service.